# GCP managed notebook connetion to Memorystore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-memorystore

I have a redis Memorystore instance.
I also have a managed notebook in vertex AI.

Connecting the notebook to the redis instance is time out.
I got:

> ConnectionError: Error 110 connecting to 10.*.*.*:6379. Connection
> timed out.

Is there any configuration I need to do so that the notebook can see the redis instance?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the MemoryStore address is a private IP address (RFC 1918). Only systems within the same VPC can connect. Vertex AI is located in a different network. Google offers peering to connect networks together.

Configure VPC network peering for Vertex AI so that it can network with the VPC that contains MemoryStore.

[Vertex AI: Set up VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/vpc-peering)

Comment: I've already tried that. Did not work!

Comment: Both of Notebook and the Redis are in the same region, and they share the same network, the default network.

Comment: @M.M - Edit your post with more details. Since the address is private (anything that starts with 10.x.x.x) show the address. authorization settings, how you are connecting, etc. If the two were in the same VPC network then you would not have been able to establish peers, add more details about that.